# In LTE, which occurs first during mobile attachment: RRC Connection or NAS Procedure?

Tags: network-core, mobile, lte

I'm digging into the LTE attachment procedure and I'm trying to understand the correct sequence of events. During the initial attachment of a mobile device to an LTE network, there appears to be some interplay between the Radio Resource Control (RRC) connection setup and the Non-Access Stratum (NAS) procedures, specifically the attach request. Can someone clarify the precise order in which these processes occur? Which is initiated first when a device powers up in an LTE area - the RRC connection to establish the radio link or the NAS procedure for the core network attachment? Any detailed explanation or reference to the 3GPP specs would be greatly appreciated.